# How to get the user_agent details in websockets in nest?

Tags: typescript, websocket, nestjs

```
generateMetaData(client: Socket) {
    return {
        ip_info: {
            ip: client.handshake.address,
            public_ip: client.handshake.headers['cf-connecting-ip'],
            forwarded_ip: client.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for']
        },
        agent_info: {
            agent: client.handshake.headers['user-agent']
        },
        request_meta: {
            uri: client.handshake.url,
            country_code: client.handshake.headers['cf-ipcountry'],
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        },
    };
}
```

I tried to get `user_agent` from headers through a socket connection, but no value is being retrieved from headers.
The problem is that I need `user_agent` details.